# Which match takes precedence when exporting an NFS share?

Tags: permissions, network-share, nfs

Say you're exporting an NFS share using IP addresses and netmasks to give different machines different permissions:

```
[/etc/exports]
/media/shared 192.168.0.64/26(rw,[...]) 192.168.0.0/24(ro,[...])
```

In case the ranges overlap and a machine will match both expressions, which one will take precedence? Is this allowed? What permissions will this client get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case first match wins since the two expressions are of the same type.  (A single host expression would win even if it came after the IP subnet expression because it has precedence.)  See exports(5) for details.